# Add Classes to first level list tags

Tags: jquery, class

is there a way to add class to only one level on li tags? in m case at the moment it looks like this:

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
And this is what I need
<ul>
    <li class="lev-one"></li>
    <li class="lev-one">
        <ul>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="lev-one"></li>
</ul>
```

Thank you for your help in advance.

Dom

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("*:not(li) > ul > li").addClass("lev-one")
```

Comment: That will add the class to the `ul` elements

Comment: @Philippe Leybaert: Fixed that.